# Calling an Asset field from a Global

Tags: globals

I can't, for the life of me, find an answer to this question.

I have a global called **work**.  It has three Asset fields.  One is called **mediakit**, which is an upload of a PDF.  I am trying to get the file name of that asset and add it into the template but cannot find anything giving me the proper way to do this in the template

Based on the documentation I thought:

```
 {{ work.mediakit }}
```

would output something at least but nothing shows and so whittling away from there to get it to call the correct path has eluded me.

Can anyone give me the correct way to call that?

The path is:

```
  "/assets/medikit/{{ the filename of the pdf uploaded}}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assets fields always return [ElementCriteriaModel’s](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel) in templates. To get the actual related asset, do this:

```
{% set asset = work.mediakit.first() %}
```

You can’t be *sure* that there’s actually a related asset, so it’s worth making sure `work.mediakit.first()` actually returned something before accessing its properties:

```
{% if asset %}
    {{ asset.url }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: "Asset fields are always returned as arrays in templates" - I think you just helped me level up (now at level 2!)  Thanks a ton.

Comment: ...and because they are arrays, you can test if the field actually contains any images or not like this: ```{% if work.mediakit|length %}```

Comment: Technically they return [ElementCriteriaModel’s](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel), not arrays, and grabbing the first asset with `[0]` could potentially be excessive if you have more than one asset and only need the first one (as this will actually load _all_ of the assets behind the scenes, before returning the first one).